# C# and remote database connection (using Compact)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, remote-access

I'm developing an application on a Windows CE Platform and this application need a connection to a remote database (Sybase ASE). This remote database is on the internal network.

How can I do this?

It seems that ODBC isn't embedded in the Compact Framework...

The only one solution that I found was to develop an UNIX application that executes my SQL code and send it back to my C# application (using Socket...).

Better idea?

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like you need AseConnection, look here http://santu4you.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=amonth%3d10%26ayear%3d2007 may point you down a possible path.

Comment: For AseConnection, documentation says : "The ASE Enterprise .NET Data Provider is an add-on component to the .NET Framework that allows you to access a Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) database.", so, not for Compact...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to IIS, you could create a web service and call that from your Windows CE application.  This I think would be cleaner than anything you would do with raw sockets.

I don't know this for a fact, but it is very possible that the DataTable instance could be serialized and a lot of the parsing work would be done for you.

Your web method might be something like this:

```
DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query);
```

Comment: Problem is that I haven't any IIS but only the Unix machine on which the database is actually installed...

Comment: Why does he need IIS to create the service?  THe CF can consume a web service hosted by any OS.

Comment: I don't know the possibility of hosting WebServices but at beginning of the post : "If you have access to IIS" ...

Comment: A Web service is very talkative for transferring data retrieved from SQL queries. Raw sockets might not be clean depending on who implements the protocols, but working with the compact framework often means your restricted in data transfer as well, rendering raw sockets superior to Web services.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the ASE ADO.NET Data Provider.  I believe it does work with the Compact Framework.

Comment: Are you sure? As I see, ASE ADO.NET Data Provider doesn't work with CF !

Comment: @Arnaud F.  You're probably right.  I was probably thinking about SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious; doesn't [Connecting to an ASA database on Windows CE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.pocketbuilder_2.0.pkresref/html/pkresref/pkresref161.htm) documentation provide guidance for doing this on Windows CE?